# Unable to parse json array

Tags: python, json

I am just learning python and can not solve one issue.
The input json text like:

```
[1123771,10,7699,4357,'UMF Selfoss','Haukar Hafnarfjordur','2015,5,25,19,15,00','2015,5,25,20,16,37',-1,0,1,0,1,0,0,2,2,'8','7',,'True',0.25,'',25,'',2.75]
```

Then I trying to use python `json` module to parse it i get an error.
Here is the code:

```
js = json.loads("[1123771,10,7699,4357,'UMF Selfoss','Haukar Hafnarfjordur','2015,5,25,19,15,00','2015,5,25,20,16,37',-1,0,1,0,1,0,0,2,2,'8','7',,'True',0.25,'',25,'',2.75]")
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

This json text successfuly parsed by another frameworks like `json.net (C#)`.
So the question is what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your json needs to be valid in order to be able to parse it:

Use this tool :

http://jsonlint.com/

JSON only works with double quotes.

Also two consecutive commas would make your `JSON` invalid

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong JSON format. Check it by using some online services.

Comment: I don't see any validation option at this site. I tried http://jsonlint.com/
And actually that's true. meda is right. JSON needs double quotes.

Comment: sorry. you are right. So I where the simple way to convert this string to python list?